Is there a way to move the text 'Home' to the center by keeping the profile icon on the right side in dart?
I want to move the text 'Home' to the center of the bar by still keeping the profile at the right side but when I try to move the 'Home' it still seems to not be accurately centered.
What I have now
child: Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
  color: const Color(0xFFFF6947),                
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Home',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 35,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                shadows: [
                  Shadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                    blurRadius: 5,
                    offset: const Offset(1, 5),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      const CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/jerrymeme.jpg'),
        radius: 20,
      )                    
    ],
  ),
),


In your code „Home” will not be centered because in this Row CircularAvatar takes the space and Expanded fills what’s left. It causes your text to be moved a little bit to the left. Solution is to add a SizedBox in front of this Expanded that will have exactly the same size as your CircleAvatar, like this
Row(
  children: [
    SizedBox(width: 40),
    Expanded(),
    CircularAvatar(radius: 20)
  ]
)

or by creating a Stack with CircleAvatar on the right and Text centered like this:
  Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        right: 0,
        child: CircularAvatar()
      )
      Center(
        child: Text()
      )
    ],
  )

